# "No such file or directory" while the names of the file and the image are correct

Tags: python, image, file, path

I'm kind of new to coding, so I'm following a tutorial on how to make a small simple game, but when it came to putting the images in the game, the op of the tutorial doesn't really show his files and where the images are. So I tried to make something similar to him, it didn't work, and then tried to make an absolute path instead, but it still shows me "No such file or directory". Here is my current code:

```
def __init__(self,pos,groups):
    super().__init__(groups)
    self.image = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/norao/OneDrive/Desktop/Codage/labyrinth/rock.png').convert_alpha()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Did I make a mistake in the code itself ? Or is the error related to the files ?

Comment: If the exception is coming from pygame.image.load (you don't show the exception trace) then it's because that file doesn't exist

Comment: if you paste that path in file explorer do you get the expected file?